Number Theory, Irrational Rotations and speed of approximation.
I am currently studying ergodic theory and in particular irrational rotations of the circle. A problem I am trying to tackle is wether there exists an irrational number $\alpha$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{nT_{\alpha}^{n}x}=0$ for almost every $x\in [0,1]$, where $T_{\alpha}x:=(x+\alpha) \mod 1$. From what I've read such a property would heavily depend on which irrational number $\alpha$ is chosen. Since I've never touched number theory, I would like to ask for some directions that might help with solving my problem.

The starting number theory fact you'll want to learn is Dirichlet's theorem on Diophantine approximation. That shows that $n\alpha$ is often very close to an integer; you want the inhomogeneous version $x+n\alpha$, and you care if it's just larger than an integer rather than just smaller than one.
